# How do I calculate the aspect ratio of a width and height?

Tags: ratio

I am creating an image upload form.  I want to restrict users from uploading images that are not of the aspect ratio of 16:9.  What is the formula for calculating an aspect ratio such as this?

If w = width, h = height, r = ratio

In other words, how is 1920:1080 formulated to an answer of 16:9?

Comment: 1920/gcd(1920,1080). 1080/gcd(1920,1080).

Comment: Why don't compare $16h/9$ to $w$?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement you specified is

$$\frac{\mathrm{width}}{\mathrm{height}} = \frac{16}9\tag 1$$

However, testing this directly in some computer program is usually a bad idea because the result of the division will be floating-point — and if it is integer, the division is not exact, either.  The simplest way around it is by multiplying out $(1)$ so that all divisions disappear and the condition reads:

$$9\cdot\mathrm{width} = 16\cdot \mathrm{height} \tag 2$$

In the example of 1920:1080 = 16:9, the aspect ration fits because:

$$1920\cdot 9 = 17\,280 = 1080\cdot16$$

and the calculation only involves integers, hence there are no rounding or representation errors.

---

For example, in Python a function that returns `True` resp. `False` would read:

```
def check_aspect (width, height):
    return 9 * width == 16 * height
```

or in C/C++:

```
int check_aspect (int width, int height)
{
    return 9 * width == 16 * height;
}
```